# About Uncle Bob's clean architecture inversion of dependencies and Node.js

Tags: node.js, architecture, domain-driven-design, clean-architecture

I'm currently reading Uncle Bob's "Clean Architecture" book. So far it's an amazing book with lots of learning for me but there is something i'm failing to grasp.

How relevant is the inversion of dependency to scripting languages like Node.js

From my undestanding, inversion of dependencies, allows for the changes in lower level code to have no impact on the higher level code so long that the interface is kept. This in turns allow for module to be deployed without having to recompile the whole application.

But in Node.js, whether I import my database implementation module or an interface of it in my application layer, if my database schema changes, for example, then I would still have to change that database implementation module file and re-deploy the whole application.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Not sure if you are conflating dependency inversion with microservices, but I never heard of hot deploy being a main driver for dependency inversion?

Comment: How this question is related to domain-driven-design?

Comment: @plalx If module A requires module B and module B is modified then both module A and B need to be recompiled. If dependencies are inverted then modifying B does not require recompiling A

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What I meant is that in a compiled language you might just compile a DLL or .jar file and just deploy that.

That being said I realise now that, actually, this is unrelated to the language but more related to the deployment method.

Although I've never seen it, it is actually possible to deploy just a specific module even in JS so long as the interfaces are respected.

Also, I've realised the other benefits that interfaces provide to code maintainability which, even if that was the only benefit, would be justifying the use of it.

I will mark this thread as answered as I answered my own question, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: I'll exclude Typescript for this answer and discuss only dynamic javascript*

Node js is an interpreted language, there is no compilation, so it's runtime is different then compiled languages like Java, C#, etc.

The other very important difference is that javascript is a weak-typed language, so most of the errors you will encounter are at runtime, unlike compiled strong-typed languages.

Compiled strong-typed languages require knowledge of *what is the thing* (class, interface, method params, etc.) that you use, and how it looks like at compile time.

You don't have this problem with dynamic scripting languages. There, what you see is *runtime* checks against the thing that you call (for example a function) if it's not there an error is thrown.

That being said, in Node you do not have to recompile your application when you make changes, but you do need to redeploy the new changes.

In compiled languages, you do need to recompile a certain portion of the application that is affected by the change and also you deploy that change, so both need redeployment, but this one needs to be recompiled too.

Usually, these applications are divided into separate binaries, some are libraries others are executables, so you will have to recompile only a subset of the binaries.

In both compiled and interpreted languages when you change a portion of the code other portions that depend on it will be affected by the change. Now what you want is to minimize what portion of the code will be affected.

When you redeploy you do need to restart the process that is executing your application. In Node, you need to restart it so it will start running your new code.

In compiled languages, you need to restart the executable so it will run your new code, so it's pretty much the same.

Both interpreted and compiled languages have mechanisms to load dynamically a library (dll) or javascript modules that simply text files, so it's not necessary to restart the process.

Just because you don't have explicit interfaces in Javascript like you have in Java or C#, it doesn't mean that you are not *bound and dependent on interfaces*. If your code calls a function on an object, this code *expects* that this function will be there, so it's part of the interface of the object. You can change the implementation of this function without having to change the calling code because it depends on the name and arguments of the function, not the implementation.

The dependency inversion can be applied to Node too, it's just that you have *implicit* interfaces instead of explicitly defined ones. You just need to think in terms of abstractions and define the interface in such a way that it's not bound to any implementation details.

If you change the interface, both implementation and client code is affected. If you change the implementation only, clients of the interface are not affected. That applies to both weak-typed and strong-typed languages whether this happens at runtime of compile time.

Whether you need to recompile is specific to the language and whether you can do a redeploy without having to restart the process is another matter. The big question is "What do you change, the interface, or the implementation?"

The example that you gave with the database needs more details on what changes. Your schema might change without affecting the interfaces, only the implementation. It may change because there are significant changes to the rest of the application and this will affect some portions of it.

If you change only the implementation, not the interface (function names, definitions, etc.) you only change the DB module, so higher-level code is not affected. Dependency inversion works and higher-level code is not affected.

It's true that it's easier to understand it in languages in C# and Java that have explicit interfaces and there is another step, compilation involved. It's difficult to imagine the same thing with *implicit interfaces* in javascript, but on an abstract level it's the same, just the mechanisms are different. In both types of languages, if you change in interface, code breaks, that's pretty much it.

That's why you should define abstractions and interfaces and keep changes to them under control, so your code doesn't break. Of course interfaces will need to change also. When they do you need to update client code. This applies to both types of languages too.